# Check C++ reference setter value

Tags: c++, reference, getter-setter

I have a question about the much-commented-about C++ reference getter-setter in C++. This is the base code:

```
class Foo
{
     X x_;
public:
          X & x()       { return x_; }
    const X & x() const { return x_; }
}
```

My issue with this is: what if I need to check the value when I set it? Let's imagine that I'm setting the latitude of a coordinate. If I were writing a `setLat` method, it would look like this:

```
void MyClass::setLat(double lat)
{
    if (lat < -90 || lat > 90)
    {
        throw std::range_error("The latitude must be between -90 and 90.");
    }
    _lat = lat;
}
```

Can I do something similar with:

```
double & MyClass::lat()
{
    return _lat;
}
```

### Thanks

When I saw the code at the top of this question as the answer of another StackOverflow question, I thought, "Cool." But then, I ended up realizing what people here are saying: it breaks encapsulation. This member might just as well be public.

Since I don't use C++ that often, I wasn't too sure, thought.

The answer given by @ted-lyngmo did however make a lot of sense. I think that just having a regluar getter and a setter might in the end be the best. But I *thought* it might be possible to mimic the property ability of C# and Python in recent versions of C++. It looks like it is. Now: is it a good idea to do it? The question still seems open.

Comment: returning a non-const reference is not encapsulation. If you want encapsulation then do not return a non-const reference

Comment: Any caller could save the returned reference, and then modify the member at any time. The member could just as well be public.

Comment: Getter would look like this: `X x() const { return x_; }`.  Setter would look like this: `void set_x(X value) { x_ = std::move(value); }`.  What `Foo` has is encapsulation breaking references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to make a user-defined type of latitude and put all validations in that:

```cpp
class Latitude {
public:
    Latitude() = default;
    
    explicit Latitude(double lat) : m_latitude(lat) {
        if (m_latitude < -90 || m_latitude > 90)
            throw std::range_error("The latitude must be between -90 and 90.");
    }

    explicit operator double() const { return m_latitude; }

private:
    double m_latitude = 0.;
};
```

That way you could keep the class containing a latitude clean:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    void setLat(Latitude lat) {
        _lat = lat; 
    }

private:
    Latitude _lat;
};
```

or

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    Latitude& latitude() {
        return _lat;
    }

private:
    Latitude _lat;
};
```

Comment: This is completely theoretical for me right now, but it might be possible to make a template out of this and to pass the checking code as a lambda in order to have a fully reusable class. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it might be possible. I'm mostly trying to grok how C++ works. This was a great example. Thanks!

Comment: @eje211 Glad it helped! You're welcome! Yes, using class templates is good when you want to do similar things with different underlying types. Instead of plain `int`s or `double`s one could create an `interval` class template that could be a base class for `Latitude` and similar types with a specific valid interval etc.

Comment: I understand templated. I've used Java, C#, and Scala. The concept is the same as generics in those languages. Templates are the same in principle, but, like everything C++, they just feel very different. (And I know they don't work like on the JVM at all under the hood. Generics are implemented at runtime on the JVM and at compile-time in C# and for C++'s templates.) For example, value categories (rvalue, lvalue, prvalue, xvalue, glvalue) are, in my experience, something that exists only in C++, at least to that extent.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a non-const reference breaks encapsulation. The caller can do anything they like once they have the reference. The behavior you want can be achieved by returning a proxy:

```
#include<iostream>

struct foo {
    struct proxy {
        proxy(int& _value) : _value(_value) {}
        proxy& operator=(int value) {
            if (value != 42) throw "bad value";
            _value = value;
            return *this;
        }
        operator int () { return _value; }
        private:
        int& _value;
    };
    proxy get() { return {x}; }
    int get() const { return x; }
    private:
    int x = 0;
};


int main(){
    foo f;
    f.get() = 42;
    std::cout << f.get();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4ovGcqe9M)

However, it is much simpler to provide an actual setter `foo::set(int)`.

Comment: I would qualify accessor functions of `proxy` as rvalue(`&&`), such that if user code stores them by value, a diagnostic is generated.

Comment: I'd probably just prefer a setter with a parameter.